# Predict outcome in R

Tags: r

I have been using the `predict` function in `R` to predict a `randomForests` model outcomes for a testing set when it suddenly it would only return the predicted levels instead of the probabilities. I specified the type as response but it still returns factors. What possibly could cause this?

The data consists in 23 variables, 20 of which are factors (unordered) and two of which are numeric. I am trying to predict whether a product will sell or not (0 or 1). Here is the code for the prediction:

```
library(randomForest) 
rf = randomForest(sold ~., data = train, ntree=200, nodesize=25) 
prf <- predict(rf, newdata = test, type ="response")
```

Comment: Please show us code

Comment: @cad86 Edit your question. People shouldn't have to dig through the comments to find relevant information.

Comment: Thank you for posting your code. Also, please include a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestion. I'll try to produce such an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set type="prob"

```
data(iris)
library(randomForest) 
seed(1234)
train.key = sort(sample(1:dim(iris)[1],100))
iris.train = iris[train.key,]
iris.test  = iris[-train.key,]
rf = randomForest(Species ~., data = iris.train) 
predicted.prob = predict(rf,newData=iris.test,type ="prob")
```